# Remove rows from a 2d array where any column value matches a given value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

For example, i have the following multidimensional array (an array of associative arrays):

```
array(
[0]=> (array('key01'=>'value01', 'key02'=>'value02')),
[1]=> (array('key11'=>'value11', 'key12'=>'value12')),
[2]=> (array('key21'=>'value21', 'key22'=>'value22')),
...
[N]=> (array('keyN1'=>'valueN1','keyN2'=>'valueN2'))
);
```

I'm looking for a native method (if exists) that find a value in that array and remove the corresponding row. For example, i would remove row that contains value value21, the resulting array is the following:

```
array(
[0]=> (array('key01'=>'value01', 'key02'=>'value02')),
[1]=> (array('key11'=>'value11', 'key12'=>'value12')),
...
[N]=> (array('keyN1'=>'valueN1','keyN2'=>'valueN2'))
);
```

(i would not use for loops if possible...)

Comment: it is not possible. Loop over array and use `unset`

Comment: No, it isn't db related...

Comment: Not a single function no, but plenty of one-liners that chain functions, e.g., `array_filter($array, function ($innerArray) { return in_array("search value", $innerArray); });`

Comment: @u_mulder after i use unset, row will disappear, or i have a null row (and in this case i have to do another for loop to remove that null row...)?

Comment: It will disappear. Instead of asking questions - write a code and make a test,

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_filter() with closure to achieve this.

```
    $myArr = array(
            array('key01'=>'value01', 'key02'=>'value02'),
            array('key11'=>'value11', 'key12'=>'value12'),
            array('key21'=>'value21', 'key22'=>'value22'),
    );


    $finalArr = array_filter($myArr,function($val1){
                      $flag = true;
                      array_filter($val1,function($val2) use(&$flag){
                               if($val2 == 'value21'){
                                     $flag=false;
                               }
                      });

                      return $flag;
                });

    $finalArr = array_values($finalArr); // to get the array numerically indexed in order
```

But I will have to say that doing a nested `foreach` with `unset()` is almost similar. Hope it helps.

**Edit:**

in_array() in the closure is much simpler

```
$finalArr = array_filter($myArr,function($val1){
                  return ! in_array("value21",$val1);
            });
```

Also remember that there is no use of closure here rather lambda, both of them are anonymous functions.

Comment: Why not use `return in_array('value21', $val1);` inside the closure ?

Comment: you can absolutely use that, i just enjoyed writing nested array_filter() and got caught up, that would be the even simple. I've edited my answer using in_array() but remember now the closure is gone and we are using lambda in the initial array_filter()

Comment: I most certainly would not recommend or use the first snippet -- it is abusing the design structure of `array_filter()` and does not enjoy the possibility of short circuiting on a filterable row.  I would use the modern arrow function syntax version of the second snippet as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72060362/2943403).